# Почему происходит выход за пределы массива?Перевод числа из 16 сс в 2 сс)( В цикле for(int i = size_binarr; i > 0;i -= 4) str[i]= 'M')

Tags: c++, c, массивы, системы-счисления

```
int StrLength(char *str);

int HexToBin(char *str);

void CharToInt(char *str);


int HexToBin(char *str)
{
    CharToInt(str);
    int size_str = StrLength(str);
    int size_binarr = StrLength(str) * 4;
    int *binarr= new int[size_binarr];

    for (int i = size_binarr; i > 0;i -= 4)//1,2,3
    {
        for (int j = 4; j > 0; j--)
        {
            binarr[i] = str[size_str] % 2;
            binarr[i - 1] = str[size_str] / 2;
        }
        str--;
    }
    return *binarr;
}

int StrLength(char *str)
{
    int count = 0;

    while (*str)
    {
        str++;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

void CharToInt(char *str)
{
    int size = StrLength(str);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] >= '1' && '9' >= str[i])
            str[i] = int(str[i]) - 48;
        else if (str[i] >= 'A' && 'F' >= str[i])
            str[i] = int(str[i]) - 31;
    }
}
```

Comment: скорее всего потому что индексация начинается с 0, поэтому максимальный индекс: length-1

Comment: Исправил, не помогло.

Comment: что именно и как ты исправил?

Comment: Заменил длину массива (size_binarr) на (size_binarr - 1) и (size_str) на (size_str - 1). Основная проблема в том, что в str[i] у меня появляется 'M', хотя этого не должно быть.

Answer (score 2):

Вы начинаете цикл с `int i = size_binarr`, а затем обращаетесь к `binarr[i]`. Но `binarr` имеет размер `size_binarr`, т.е. его последний элемент будет иметь индекс `size_binarr - 1`, а вы обращаетесь по индексу `i = size_binarr`. Советую переделать все циклы в формат `for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {/*...*/}` и не забывать, что индексация начинается с нуля.